# enet_host_create returns NULL on Windows

Tags: enet

I wrote a sample code using ENet, which was working fine under Linux but on Windows, enet_host_create returns NULL. This is a strange behavior since enet_host_create is one of the first function called while using ENet, previously any connection attempt.

Answer (score 0):

enet_host_create returns NULL on Windows when you don't call enet_initialize() previously. Don't forget to call enet_deinitialize() when you're done with the library, or at the exit of your program.

A program using ENET without calling the initialize function *could* work on linux since this function doesn't do much on this platform. But on Windows, it will fail.

Thanks to the ENet community for their help resolving this issue.